# What is the least $n\ge1$ for which there is an $n$-dimensional closed flat manifold with perfect fundamental group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology

In answer to the question "[Is there a flat manifold with trivial first homology?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434822/is-there-a-flat-manifold-with-trivial-first-homology)" I proposed choosing a finite perfect group $P$ and a surjection $\phi:F\to P$ where $F$ is a free group of finite rank. If $K$ is the kernel of $\phi$ then the group $G:=[F,F]/[K,K]$ is perfect, torsion-free, finitely generated and abelian-by-finite.

This construction is not novel. I believe it is a standard strategy for obtaining torsion-free perfect groups.

The Hirsch length of $G$ is the dimension of a closed flat manifold with fundamental group $G$. One might hope to achieve the smallest possible Hirsch length by taking $P$ to be the alternating group $A_5$ and taking $F$ to be free on two generators. In that case the kernel $K$ is free on 61 generators by the Nielsen-Schreier Theorem, and $F/[K,K]$ has Hirsch length 61. Since $F/[F,F]$ has Hirsch length 2 we find that $G$, in this example, is a perfect f.g. abelian-by-finite group of Hirsch length 59. Is 59 the least dimension for which this phenomenon occurs? Maybe it is possible to factor out some of the rank 59 abelian normal subgroup in $G$ without sacrificing torsion-freeness. $G$, like any crystallographic group, has a unique largest abelian subgroup of finite index $A$ and it would be useful to know the constituents of the $\mathbb QP$-module $V:=A\otimes\mathbb Q$ as a $\mathbb QP$-module.

From this discussion, and the known fact that upto dimension 3 there are no perfect flat manifolds, the answer to the question lies in the range $4 \le n \le 59$. Can this be pinned down?

Addendum 16 January 2023: the comments below strongly support n=15 for the minimum possible.

Comment: In terms of groups, I think you're asking for the smallest $d\ge 1$ such that there exists a perfect, torsion-free, virtually $\mathbf{Z}^d$ group.

Comment: There is apparently a complete classification of closed flat 4-manifold, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6613.pdf, and according to their tables 4 and 5 none of these groups are perfect.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: It looks like the relevant table is Table 3, which handles the orientable case. Tables 4 and 5 handle the non-orientable case, which will always surject $C_2$.

Comment: @HJRW: thanks for the correction!

Comment: The minimal dimension is indeed 15. Lutowski and Szczepański just showed in https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.11368 that 15 is the minimal dimension in which there exists a non-solvable Bieberbach group. Since nontrivial solvable groups aren't perfect, this does the job.

Answer (score 7):

For $G=A_5=\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$, the minimal dimension of a flat manifold with holonomy group $G$ is <s>12</s> 15 according to Theorem (V.1) in W. Plesken:``Minimal dimensions for flat manifolds with prescribed holonomy’’, Math. Ann., 284,477–486, 1989.

Comment: [DOI link to Plesken's paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01442498) (behind expensive Springer paywall)

Comment: @KasperAnderson  This is definitely a strong hint at 12. It seems implausible that allowing other perfect holonomy groups in place of $A_5$ would enable a reduction to 11 or less. I am just holding back from ticking this answer while I think about this last ingredient. I accept that at a common sense level, Plesken has addressed the question head on and has answers. The Plesken paper is quite technical and in some ways I feel it would be attractive to have a clean simple route into this question.

Comment: @KasperAnderson J. A. Hillman emailed me to make some comments one of which was that the rank should be 15 not 12. I have gone over Plesken's formula applying Theorem V.1 when p=5 and I agree with Hillman: the minimal dimension with A_5 as holonomy seems to come out as 15 if we accept Plesken's formula. (I have not gone through the detail of Plesken's proof, I am just using the displayed formula on page 483 of his paper.

Comment: @PeterKropholler Thanks, I computed this too quickly.... I also found the result 15 for $A_5$ in Hiss' presentation https://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gerhard.Hiss/Presentations/Aberdeen05Talk.pdf (page 14). However Hiss claims that for $\text{PSL}_2(7)$ the answer is 23, I get 15 in this case as well...

Comment: Can you expand on why minimality of dimension implies the manifold has trivial first homology?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Flat manifolds are aspherical which means that the homology of the manifold and its fundamental group coincide. On the group theory side, the fist homology of a group with trivial integer coefficients is isomorphic to the largest abelian quotient of the group. So perfect fundamental group amounts to the same condition as trivial first homology for these manifolds. In particular, it's not really a feature that is influenced by minimality.

Comment: @Peter:  I am still confused, because the holonomy group doesn't determine the fundamental group, nor does it determine $H_1$.  As Igor mentions in his answer in the post you linked to, if $\pi$ is the fundamental group of flat manifold $M^n$ with holonomy $\phi$, then $\pi\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is also the fundamental group of a flat manifold $N^{n+1}$ with holonomy $\phi$, and clearly $H_1(N)\cong H_1(M)\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ in this case.  Of course, minimality of the dimension in which you get holonomy $\phi$ rules out this particular construction, but why couldn't there be other constructions?

Comment: @JasonDeVito You are right that the holonomy group determines neither the fundamental group nor the first homology of the flat manifold. But it is always true that the abelianisation of the fundamental group is isomorphic to the first homology of the manifold.

Comment: @PeterKropholler:  I agree with everything you just wrote.  The way I read Igor's answer is that we start with a flat manifold $M$ with holonomy $\phi$ with $\phi$ chosen to be perfect.  Via your answer, or the Holt-Pleskin reference, we obtain a new flat manifold $N$ with holonomy $\phi$, where $\pi_1(N)$ is perfect; equivalently, $H_1(N) = 0$.  One way to rephrase my question is:  is it true that $\dim N \leq \dim M$?  If not, I still don't see why isolating the minimal dimension in which $\phi$ can be perfect answers the question (though it does provide a lower bound).

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think it likely that for a given perfect (finite) holonomy group $\phi$ there be more than one flat manifold with perfect fundamental group and with that holonomy, maybe of different dimensions. That maybe suggests that you would not expect the inequality $\dim N\le \dim M$. Or am I still missing some key point?

Comment: @PeterKropholler: Well, I suspect *I* am missing the key point because this answer has 7 upvotes.  Your question at the top is about the lowest dimension supporting a flat manifold with perfect fundamental group.  This answer addresses the lowest dimension supporting a flat manifold with perfect holonomy group.  These two groups are related (perfect fundamental group obviously implies perfect holonomy group), so this answer (and Igor's comment above) provides a lower bound of $15$ for your question.  But as far as I can tell, it doesn't imply the answer to your question is precisely $15$.